# Active Directory Programming help needed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, active-directory, network-programming

I want to make Windows Service in .NET which has to run on Windows Server 2003, 2008. The main functionalities i need are:

As soon as a network user logs in, Display his:

1. User name in Active Directory
2. Domain
3. Ip Address from where he connected

I do not want to install or run any program/script on the client machine.

Any help on how to go about developing this will be greatly appreciated. i saw some articles explaining this using the System.Environment namespace and some others but they only shed light for the local logged on user.

Comment: Define "logging into" a Windows Service.  Are you using WCF?  Some kind of custom authentication system?  How is any of this even possible if nothing is installed on the client machine?

Comment: The program has to run on the active directory server running Win 2003 or 2008. The network user machine will not have any of our custom programs installed.

Answer (score 3):

One workaround is to monitor the security event log on the windows server machine.

This assumes that the windows server 2003/2008 domain controller is set up to log successful ‘Audit logon events’.

```
     using System.Diagnostics;
     ...
     myLog = new EventLog("Security");
     myLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(OnEntryWritten);
     ...

    /// <summary>
    /// A new event is logged in the security event log.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void OnEntryWritten(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
    {
        LogNewEntry(e.Entry);
    }
```

**Windows server 2003**

You can identify a logon with event ID's 528 and 540.

The EventLogEntry instance contains property UserName which contains Domain\UserName.

The EventLogEntry instance also contains property ReplacementStrings.

To find the ip address you have to look at the ReplacementStrings string array property [13].

**Windows server 2008**

You can identify a logon with event ID 4624.

To find the UserName you have to look at the ReplacementStrings string array property [5].

To find the Domain you have to look at the ReplacementStrings string array property [6].

To find the ip address you have to look at the ReplacementStrings string array property [18].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use .NET 3.5, have a look at the [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.aspx).  The classes in there should provide a good starting point for you.

Comment: The first motive is to log the network login event and fetch the username and ip address of the remote machine. I dont see any such function in this namespace.